# Claiming air miles for Air Alaska with codeshares

Tags: airlines, loyalty-programs, alaska-airlines

I flew from CHC to AKL with AirNZ, claimed the points.
Then from AKL to NAD to HNL with Air Pacific, claimed as partner of Qantas with OneWorld.

Then flew from HNL to SEA to YVR with Alaska Airlines.  It's in its own special Mileage Plan thing, but the wiki page says it codeshares sometimes with some OneWorld airlines:

> The airline's frequent flyer program is called Mileage Plan, and their
>   lounge is called Board Room. Alaska Airlines is not part of any of the
>   three major airline alliances, but has codeshare agreements with
>   airlines that are prominent members of Oneworld, such as British
>   Airways and American Airlines, as well as prominent SkyTeam members
>   like Air France and Delta Air Lines.

Is there a way for me to find out if I can claim it for my Qantas (or heck, my AirNZ account if I can!) frequent flyer miles?

Comment: I routinely get miles for my BA club for flying with Alaska, as long as you tell them to type in the FF number at checking it should be done automatically. After the fact - you'll have to call your club service center, it might take some time (I had a similar problem with Continental and some of their partners).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alaska Airlines (AS) is a Qantas partner for mileage earning.

[Full details are on the Qantas site](http://www.qantas.com.au/fflyer/dyn/partners/airline/alaska-airlines), but basically you'll earn 1 Qantas point per mile flown in most booking classes (but be sure to check your booking class to make sure!). You will NOT earn any Qantas Status Credits when flying with AS.

As you've already flown you'll need to go through the process to claim missing points.
There a [list of airlines that you can claim online for](http://www.qantas.com.au/fflyer/dyn/yourAccount/yourPoints/claimPoints) (not including AS!), and at the bottom of the list are the instructions for other airlines not listed. Personally I'd call first, before sending anything in. You may also be able to get away with scanning/emailing rather than posting.

Comment: Sound easy enough, but their drop down list of partners doesn't include any AS or Alaskan Airlines, or variant thereof.  And the tickets themselves don't show any other listed name for the flight.  AS0860 and AS2264 :/

Comment: Answer updated to cover claiming after the fact.  Next time, give your number when booking/checking in to avoid the pain :)

Comment: @MarkMayo See http://www.qantas.com.au/fflyer/dyn/partners/airline/alaska-airlines .